# Overloading ObjC struct for C++ unordered containers hash support

Tags: xcode, struct, operator-overloading, objective-c++

I have created `std::unordered_map<CGPoint, unsigned int>`, and obviously, to make it work I should write hash function for it:

```
namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<CGPoint> {
        inline size_t operator()(const CGPoint & v) const {
            size_t seed = 0;
            ::hash_combine(seed, v.x);
            ::hash_combine(seed, v.y);
            return seed;
        }
    };
};
```

But it was not compiling, and I found that there is a place, where equality operator should be define. So I have written following code into template struct.

```
friend bool operator==(const CGPoint& p1, const CGPoint& p2) {
    return (p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y);
}
```

But it keeps throwing exceptions:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/functional:659:21:
>   Invalid operands to binary expression ('const CGPoint' and 'const
>   CGPoint')

And:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/__hash_table:1993:32:
>   No matching function for call to object of type 'key_equal' (aka
>   'std::__1::__unordered_map_equal,
>   std::__1::equal_to, true>')

Most likely I am missing something very simple, but as it usually happens, I can't get it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried providing a version of `==` which takes `const CGPoint`s rather than `const CGPoint&`s?

Comment: Its not working. Once you define funcs for both (&v) and (v) function call becomes ambiguous as they provide the same option. It only adds some errors.

Comment: It's not "throwing exceptions".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator==` should be a top level function, not a friend function.

The following will compile:

```
namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<CGPoint> {
        inline size_t operator()(const CGPoint & v) const {
            size_t seed = 0;
            ::hash_combine(seed, v.x);
            ::hash_combine(seed, v.y);
            return seed;
        }
    };
};

bool operator==(const CGPoint& p1, const CGPoint& p2) {
    return (p1.x == p2.x) && (p1.y == p2.y);
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<CGPoint, unsigned int> map;
    map[CGPointMake(1, 1)] = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It can be a friend too, but there needs to be a declaration outside the class, not only the friend declaration.